# Contains condition over clob in sybase db

Tags: sql, database, sybase

Can someone help me with the syntax of CONTAINS in Sybase, I have tried below two, and both didn't work :

Query1:

```
select * from test where column_1 CONTAINS('Set');
```

Exception:

```
[Code: 102, SQL State: 37000]  Incorrect syntax near 'CONTAINS'.
```

Query2:

```
select * from test where CONTAINS(column_1, 'Set');
```

Exception:

```
[Code: 102, SQL State: 37000]  Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove where from your statement and that will be like below

```
select * from test  CONTAINS(column_1, 'Set');
```

[more about contains in sybase read documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01268.1520/html/iquda/BABDFAJI.htm)