# Unable to run contains query

Tags: sql, sybase

I am unable to run a contains query in my sybase database.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
from party CONTAINS(nm_first,'ghjg')
```

On running the above query, I get an error message

> "Table User-Defined Function 'party' not found"  Error: 7306

Is this a bug? I am unable to find enough resources to find appropriate solution.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: IN sybase, WHERE keyword is not used with CONTAINS, I got the reference from the below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551061/contains-condition-over-clob-in-sybase-db

Comment: But did you try _with one_ since, in every flavor of SQL I know, it makes more sense to have one? Note both forms here, for example: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/full-text-search-what-is-it.html The problem in the linked question was not the presence of `WHERE` but rather they used `CONTAINS` incorrectly. They had `where column_1 CONTAINS('Set')` instead of `where CONTAINS( column_1, 'Set')`.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? SQLAnywhere and IQ (uses SQLAnywhere as a front-end db) have support for `contains()`; ASE does not have support for `contains()`; can't speak for Advantage

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead

```
SELECT * 
FROM party 
WHERE nm_first LIKE '%ghjg%'
```